# search key only in context in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an xml which has multiple parent nodes within it. Need to be able to search for a node within each parent. Had to use key as my input (in the below example '4' in the jey statement) is derived dynamically from another node. How can set the context of key lookup to where it is being called from?

**My input**

```
<homes>
    <home>
        <to-reno>one</to-reno>
        <bedrooms name="master1">1</bedrooms>
        <bedrooms name="master2">2</bedrooms>
        <bedrooms name="master3">3</bedrooms>

    </home>
    <home>
        <to-reno>two</to-reno>
        <bedrooms name="master4">4</bedrooms>
        <bedrooms name="master5">5</bedrooms>
    </home>
</homes>
```

**Xslt**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="data-set" match="bedrooms" use="."/>
    
    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="home">
        <xsl:variable name="keyNode" select="key('data-set', '4')"/>
        <xsl:if test="$keyNode">
            <to-reno>
                <type>
                    <xsl:value-of select="to-reno"/>
                </type>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$keyNode/@name"/>
                </name>
            </to-reno>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output**

```
<homes>
    <to-reno>
        <type>one</type>
        <name>master4</name>
    </to-reno>
    <to-reno>
        <type>two</type>
        <name>master4</name>
    </to-reno>
</homes>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<homes>
    <to-reno>
        <type>two</type>
        <name>master4</name>
    </to-reno>
</homes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the third argument of the key function to pass in the root element of the subtree you want to search so in your case I think you want e.g. `<xsl:variable name="keyNode" select="key('data-set', '4', .)"/>`.